# Reactjs every time refreshing page on setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [MultiSelect Plugin](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) for Select DropDown. Here onChange event I'm storing the value in setState. Here is below code :

```
$('#selectbox-id-onChange').multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
         var newArray = this.state.options.slice();
         newArray.push($(option).val());
         this.setState({options: newArray});           
    }
});
```

The above code is working fine, I'm able to store the array value in **state** also. But the only issue is that page is refreshing everytime while storing the value in state.

Please do let me know where I'm going wrong here. I tried to figure out but couldn't get the solution.

Comment: Why you are are jquery plugin with react. I will suggest to use React version of above plugin. https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: React will rerender the component whenever the state changes.

Comment: React will re-render every time the state changes. That's why it keeps on refreshing / updating the component. Have you tried using it with `onBlur` instead of `onChange`? `onBlur` method will trigger when leaving the component.

Comment: @Ved, thanks for your update. I'll surely look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's what React is meant to do. If you do not want it not to re-render then you have to override the shouldComponentUpdate method.

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false; // Will cause component to never re-render.
}
```

Comment: which shouldn't be an ideal thing to do, Also I think a refresh should be different from a rerender, setState causes a rerender and not a refresh

Comment: @Alex, thanks for your updates. It's working fine now.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am facing the problem can you suggest something. My page is refreshing instead of rerendering.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri My apologies. Bad language. I mean re-render. I have updated my answer.